# How to Make Container Fill The Form in LWUIT

Tags: forms, java-me, containers, lwuit

I have a `Form` that take a `BoxLayout`, to be able to add different custom controls one after the other in the Y-AXIS

but there is a `Component` that I need to add in the bottom of the screen, but as I'm using the `BoxLayout` so I can't fix it size to bottom of the screen

So I think that I can set that `Container` of the control to fill the parent `Form`

So the question is how to make `Container` fill the parent `Form` in LWUIT

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try to put a `BorderLayout` in the `Form`?

You can put `Containers` in CENTER and SOUTH positions, and they let you place your controls as you want (BoxLayout Axis Y in the center).

Is that what you want?